# How to export object from module.exports?

Tags: node.js

I need to require a file passing a parameter, for this I used the following syntax:

```
module.exports = function(bot) {
    const menu = new TelegrafInlineMenu(bot);
    return menu;
};
```

the problem's that the code above export the function, I need to return the `menu` object, is there a way to do this?

I require the script using:

```
const menu = require('menu')(bot);
```

problem's that `menu` is a function not an object

Comment: `module.exports = new TelegrafInlineMenu(bot);`? But how would you know what the argument is, in that case?

Comment: @VLAZ I can't know what is the argument, I don't fully understand where do you take the `bot` parameter

Comment: If you intend your library usage to be `const menu = require('menu')(someBot);`, then the export you defined is correct.

Comment: Then how would you export an object, if you don't have the data you need to create it?

Comment: @samthecodingman but in that way the code return the function not the object `menu`

Comment: @VLAZ you're right, but I can pass the argument only via  `module.exports = function(bot)`

Comment: If you would not use a parameter, you could export a plain object instead of a function. But as your result depends on the parameter, why the current structure bothers you?

Comment: How are you using this export? I mean can you share the code by which you are calling this function?

Comment: @sfarzoso OK, therefore, you *cannot* export an object since you need more data to create the object first. Why do you think you need to export the object alone, in this case?

Comment: @Vlaz please check my update, thanks

Comment: Are you trying to export the type as well as the constructor? If so, take a look at my answer below (it wouldn't fit in a comment) and see if that meets your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function TelegrafInlineMenu(bot) {
  // constructor
  if (!(this instanceof TelegrafInlineMenu)) {
    return new TelegrafInlineMenu(bot);
  }
}

TelegrafInlineMenu.prototype.someFunction = function () {
  // etc.
};

module.exports = TelegrafInlineMenu;
```

Comment: If this achieves what you are looking for, I'll flesh out some explanation to accompany it.

Comment: I appreciate your help, but I guess I wasn't clear enough and I apologize for that. I simply need to return the object `menu` from the required file, the problem's that I need to pass the `bot` parameter, so I'm oblijed to use `module.exports = function(bot)` which return the `function` not the `menu` object, +1 for the help

Comment: How do you know that it's returning a `function`? Because the code `const menu = require('menu')(bot)` will evaluate as `const menu = new TelegrafInlineMenu(bot)` with your original code - exactly as you desire.

Comment: when I do: `console.log(menu)` it return: `[Function]` where `let menu = require('menu')(bot)`